# Find unknown coefficient of a matrix with known rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let there be a matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 7 & 5 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & λ \end{bmatrix}$.

Find the `λ` value, for which `matrix A` has a `rank(A) = 2`.

First I need to do the `reduced row echelon form` (I guess). Should I start by dividing the first row by 8 or by substracting the third row from the first? Will the result be the same? How should I proceed with the information `rank(A) = 2` given?

Comment: Yes you should start row reducing. It does not matter the order in which you perform the row operations, however certain orders may be more efficient, but they will produce the same result (assuming no mistakes are made).

Comment: What does rank mean? Have you checked the definitions? First step to solving a problem is often to check the definitions.

Comment: @amsmath how would computing the determinant help to get a rank $2$ matrix?

Comment: @Dave Think about it.

Comment: @amsmath I'm still confused: if the determinant is zero we only know that the rank is $\leq 2$, but if the determinant is nonzero we know the rank is $3$.

Comment: The matrix contains at least two linearly-independent rows. So the rank must be at least $2$. If the rank is $2$ then the determinant must be $0$.

Comment: @Dave Notice that row 1 and row 2 are linearly independent so rank $\ne 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's fair. I was thinking the OP should practice a more general method of finding the rank, but in this case yes the determinant can determine it.

Comment: From the comments above what I understood is this: 

Since the `rank(A) = 2` , then the `determinant(A)` must be `zero`. 



Thus 8$\times$(5$\times$λ - 6$\times$8) - 7$\times$(4$\times$λ - 6$\times$7) + 5$\times$(4$\times$8 - 5$\times$7) = 0 $\iff$

40λ - 384 - 28λ + 294 + 160 - 175 = 0 $\iff$

12λ - 384 - 294 + 160 - 175 = 0 $\iff$

12λ = 105 $\iff$

λ = 8.75        

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  You need row $3$ to be a linear combination of rows $1$ and $2$.  Write $a(8,7,5)+b(4,5,6)=(7,8,\lambda) $.

Solve the system  $\begin{cases}{8a+4b=7 \\7a+5b=8}\end{cases}$ for $a$ and $b$.

Then $\lambda =5a+6b$.

If we let $M=\begin{pmatrix}8&4\\7&5\end{pmatrix}$, then $M^{-1}=\frac1{12}\begin{pmatrix}5&-4\\-7&8\end{pmatrix}$.

Thus

> $\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\end{pmatrix}=M^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}7\\8\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac14\\\frac54\end{pmatrix}\,\therefore \lambda =\frac{35}4$

Answer (score 0):

You want to process by Gauss-Jordan elimination.
So you want to find the set of elementary operations to find the rank.

I recommend starting with the following operations:

1. Line 2 becomes line 2 - half of line 1
2. Line 3 becomes line 3 - (7/8) of line 1

See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: "lines" of matrices are called "rows".

Comment: Or "ligne" in french :)

Comment: Fine. But we are talking english here, right? So we have rows.

Answer (score 0):

The two first rows are linearly independent, therefore the rank is 2 or 3. To have the rank 2, one can solve $\det A = 0.$ It is a linear equation in $\lambda$ with unique solution.